# Set opacity color in google map polygon in Flutter

Tags: android, api, flutter, android-studio, google-maps

Is somebody know how can I set the opacity color in my polygon coordinates, I just want the black background in my polygon set the color to purple which has the opacity color
and same also to the border of the polygon. It is possible?.It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.

[image]

*my polygon*

```
  Set<Polygon> myPolygon() {
    List<LatLng> polygonCoords = new List();
    polygonCoords.add(LatLng(8.9442, 125.5321));
    polygonCoords.add(LatLng(8.9486, 125.5364));
    polygonCoords.add(LatLng(8.9303, 125.5384));
    polygonCoords.add(LatLng(8.9442, 125.5321));
    Set<Polygon> polygonSet = new Set();
    polygonSet.add(Polygon(
        polygonId: PolygonId('test'),
        points: polygonCoords,
        strokeColor: Colors.red));  //color of the border
    return polygonSet;
  }
```

*My google map*

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Google Map API'),
        ),
        body:Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
            child: GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated:  _onMapCreated,
              polygons: myPolygon(), markers: _markers,
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition:CameraPosition(target: LatLng(8.9405, 125.5364),
                zoom: 15,
            ))
        ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 polygonSet.add(Polygon(
        polygonId: PolygonId('test'),
        points: polygonCoords,
        fillColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
        strokeColor: Colors.red));  //color of the border
```

Comment: thanks it's work but it is possible to convert the color hex? just like this ? `const Color(0xFFFF5800)`

Comment: yes, fillColor: Color(0xFFFF5800).withOpacity(0.2),

Answer (score 0):

Add-on to @JimChiu's answer, you can use hex color like this,

```
class HexColor extends Color {
  HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));

  static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
    hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll('#', '');
    if (hexColor.length == 6) {
      hexColor = 'FF' + hexColor;
    }
    return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
  }
}
```

And you can use like this.

```
polygonSet.add(Polygon(
        polygonId: PolygonId('test'),
        points: polygonCoords,
        strokeColor: HexColor('#88F04857')));
```